# How to read SQL binary field in C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, binary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SELECT @@DBTS using Linq to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528486/select-dbts-using-linq-to-sql)
>   [Sql binary to c# - How to get SQL binary equivalent of binary in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10926192/sql-binary-to-c-sharp-how-to-get-sql-binary-equivalent-of-binary-in-c-sharp)

I have one SQL table with one binary column. It has some data in binary format.

e.g. 0x9A8B9D9A002020202020202020202020

I am using LINQ context to fetch the data from this table. Can anyone help me in getting this.
Here is a sample code I am using,

```
IEnumerable<byte[]> query = context
                .ExecuteQuery<byte[]>("select empPWD from Employee where employeeId = E32");
```

When I run this code it gives an error, like need to do mapping something alike.

The exact error message;

> The type 'System.Byte[]' must declare a default (parameterless)
>   constructor in order to be constructed during mapping.

Please help me if anyone knows this.

Comment: Post the exact error if you want help.

Comment: What is the column type? image? varbinary?

Comment: @Ramhound - Please see my edits for exact error message. The column type is binary(16).

Comment: Hmmm you need to look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528486/select-dbts-using-linq-to-sql

Comment: @V4Vendetta - It returns an integer form. Can I fetch it as is in the form of string.

Comment: Though it is closed, it doesn't resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you refactor it to:

```
IEnumerable<System.Data.Linq.Binary> query = 
           context.Employees.Where(e => e.employeeId == "E32").Select(e => e.empPWD);
```

I think that should work (assuming your context contains an Employees table class). To access the byte[], use ToArray() on each instance of type System.Data.Linq.Binary.